# How can I set element's height the same as its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$("#topbar").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: ($(this).height() == 45) ? 20 : 45
    }, 200);
});
```

```css
#topbar {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='topbar'>
toggle me
<br>
some explanations
<br>
some more explanation

</div>
```

As you see, when you click on the orange box, its height will be increased *(and vice versa)*. But `45` isn't an enough height for current content. Actually the content of that box is dynamic. So I want to set a height the same as its content's height.

How can I do that?

Comment: `height: ($(this).height() == 20) ? this.scrollHeight : 20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using condition if height is 45 or not and then assign 20 for true and 45 for false condition. Instead, follow below code -

```js
var collapse = false;
$("#topbar").click(function () {
    var ht = (collapse? 20 : this.scrollHeight);
    collapse=!collapse;
    $(this).animate({
        height: ht
    },200);
    
});
```

```css
#topbar {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='topbar'>
toggle me
<br>
some explanations
<br>
some more explanation

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Credit goes to Jai.

```js
$("#topbar").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: ($(this).height() == 20) ? this.scrollHeight : 20
  }, 200);

});
```

```css
#topbar {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='topbar'>
  toggle me
  <br> some explanations
  <br> some more explanation
  <br> some more explanation
  <br> some more explanation
  <br> some more explanation<br> some more explanation

</div>
```